# Как правильно сделать rss reader во fragment?

Tags: android-fragment, android, activity, rss

Я сделала оболочку из фрагментов. 
Две "колонки", в одной список возможных новостей (например, политика, наука и т.п.), во второй, фрагмент в котором отображается сам список новостей по данной теме.

Вообщем, схема стандартная, но в примерах, которые я нашла, все новости наследуются от activity. Я хочу, что бы они наследовались от фрагмента. Мои попытки переписать для фрагмента не увенчались успехом. Фрагменты сами по себе, новости сами по себе. Можно сделать так как-нибудь? Если нельзя, как лучше сделать?

Comment: можно сделать все, хотим код активити, которое надо переделать во фрагмент

Comment: А можно ссылку на примеры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто переписала новости под фрагменты.